If two norms induce the same topology on a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ with an absolute value, then they are equivalent
We say two norms $\|\cdot\|_1,\|\cdot\|_2$ are equivalent if there exists reals $c,C>0$ s.t. $c\|x\|_2 \leq\|x\|_1 \leq C\|x\|_2$ for all $x\in V$.
If two norms $\|\cdot\|_1,\|\cdot\|_2$ induce the same topology on a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ with an absolute value $|\cdot|$, then are them equivalent?
The result is known to be true when the field $K$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. It is also true if $K$ is complete and $V$ is of finite dimension, in which case all norms are equivalent. But is it true when $K$ is equipped with a trivial absolute value or when $V$ is of infinite dimension?
Note that the classical approach doesn't work since we may not scale a non-zero vector $x$ to a unit vector: there may not exist $c\in K^\times$ s.t. $|c|=\|x\|^{-1}$.

@user469053 This statement "For linear maps between normed spaces, continuity is the same as Lipschitz continuity." is certainly true if we work over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, are you sure it works in the general case? I mean this is almost exactly what I want to prove here.

Thanks for spotting my error.

Let $K$ be a field with the trivial absolute value, $|x|=0$ if $x=0$ and $|x|=1$ otherwise. Let $$V=c_{00}(\mathbb{N},K)=\{f:\mathbb{N}\to K:|\text{supp}(f)|<\infty\},$$ where $$\text{supp}(f)=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:f(n)\neq 0\}.$$
For each $1\leqslant q<\infty$, define $$\|f\|_q=\Bigl(\sum_n |f(n)|^q\Bigr)^{1/q}=|\text{supp}(f)|^{1/q}.$$  Define $$\|f\|_\infty = \max_n |f(n)|.$$  Note that $$\|f\|_\infty = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & : f \neq 0 \\ 0 & : f=0.\end{array}\right.$$
Note that $|\text{supp}(f)|$ and whether or not $f=0$  are invariant under multiplying by a non-zero member of $K$, so for any $a\in K^\times$ and $f\in V$, $$\|af\|_q=\|f\|_q=|a|\|f\|_q.$$  Positive-definiteness and triangle inequality are easy to verify.
We note that if $f,g\in V$ are distinct, $\|f-g\|_q\geqslant 1$. From this it follows that $\|\cdot\|_q$ induces the discrete topology on $V$, and $(V,\|\cdot\|_q)$ is complete. However, the norms are all mutually non-equivalent, since $$\|1_{\{1,\ldots, k\}}\|_q=k^{1/q}.$$

Great counter example!
